# Is the Current Location/Compass heading button available in the iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I am working on a sample map kit app for iOS. I have everything working and a toolbar button to toggle the MKUserTrackingMode. This may seem like a silly question but I have searched all the options in the IB and looked in the documentation, and I can't find any button options like the one for the current location/compass heading used in the iOS Maps app. Is that particular button available to developers?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to create a MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem and pass it the MKMapview in the constructor, then add that button item to the navigation menu (or where ever it is your button should be).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.map];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't expect it to be it's own class, thought it would just be a button style. I even wasted time making my toggle function. It comes built into the class!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question but it sounds like you want to be setting the `userTrackingMode` property of your `MKMapView` to the`MKUserTrackingMode.MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have that part working. I am using a toolbar button with text label. I would like to replicate the button used in the Maps app to toggle the tracking mode states. I've looked all of interface builder and the docs and can't find that button.