# Is there any event that catches when the user turns the corner?

Tags: swift, ios8, navigation, watchkit

I'm writing a program on WatchKit SDK. My aim is to generate a route between user's current location and another point. And I would like to catch a moment when the user should turn the corner. At the moment I wonder, what is a proper framework to use because in fact I do not need to display the map but do need to be able to build the route and catch the turns. Could you advice the proper way to do it?

Comment: Are you referring to turning on a specific corner (i.e. when they turn right at 5th and Broadway) or anytime they turn and go in a different direction, even if that happens to be in the middle of a field?

Comment: Not with Watchkit specifically - no dev access yet to accelerometer or location on the watch itself. You'd have to get this info from the paired iPhone instead, which you could probably do by setting route w/geofencing & following advice in similar questions like this about MapKit & CLHeading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264137/ios-iphone-show-user-direction-and-orientation-in-space-like-the-compass-app-on

Comment: Do you know the GPS coordinates of that corner?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have confused you. I mean that every time the user should turn left or right when he is on a road I would like to catch it (not in the middle of the field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you will need to track the users GPS coordinate in your WatchKit extension running on their iPhone.  You will need to use the `course` and `coordinate` properties on the `CLLocation` object to determine when you are getting close or at the correct corner and then respond accordingly.

Here is some more info on tracking GPS coordinates in a WatchKit extension [How to calculate current location in WatchKit extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960108/how-to-calculate-current-location-in-watchkit-extension/27964325#27964325)