# How to reproduce button for toggling setUserTrackingMode in MapView under ios6?

Tags: ios, ios6, maps, mkmapview, mapkit

With the following code it is possible to setup a button for toggling the setUserTrackingMode in  a navigation bar.

```
// set MKUserTrackingBarButton
// source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876157/is-the-current-location-compass-  heading-button-available-in-the-ios-sdk

MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithMapView:self.mapView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;

// set tracking mode
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

How to do this the way (button lower left corner within map) Apple does this in Maps?
(Sorry, I'm not allowed to post a picture clarifying it)

Comment: Is that question so far from beeing relevant for others or is the answer more trivial than I realize? Please give the question a vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `MKUserTrackingBarButton` to a `UIToolbar` which is positioned at the bottom of the screen (and potentially has a custom background). That should allow reproducing the Maps.app behavior.