# Center the MKMapView onto my location when pressing a button

Tags: ios, mkmapview

My app includes an `MKMapView` that shows the users location as a blue bullet.

Now I made a button (just like in a normal map app) that when pressed should center the map view onto the users location, but I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 10):

You could just set map view user tracking mode to MKUserTrackingModeFollow. It would automatically set map center on user location.

```
- (IBAction)centerMapOnUserButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: I put this in my main file but it still doesn't center the map on the user location

Comment: Isn't there a way to have the map centered on the users location from the beginning ?

Comment: Make this action is triggered when you click your button.

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/K8DHW/download/centerMapView.zip <- i created sample project to demonstrate this. If you want to centre user from the beginning, set this mode in -(void)viewDidAppear method.

Answer (score 7):

```
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just been working on this problem today.

It's possible to add a MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem button to a toolbar to copy the functionality from the iOS Maps app. When pushing the button it will turn tracking on and off.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.map];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
}
```

A fuller answer is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9877574/35723).

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 Solution**

```
@IBAction func centerUserButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.mapView.setCenter(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is it :

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
        {
            locationManager.delegate = self;
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
            locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
        location = [locationManager location];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];;
        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center=coordinate;
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta=10.015; // Vary as you need the View for 
        span.longitudeDelta=10.015;
        region.span=span;
        [mapView setRegion:region];

        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Comment: I don't understand, where do I put this ? In the .m file ? Sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: YEs...Put at ViewDidLoad.