# MKMapView with annotations issue

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have MKMapView with many annotations in proper order. And I have button to change map mode:

```
- (IBAction)userDidPressTrackButton:(id)sender {
    if (self.mapView.userTrackingMode == MKUserTrackingModeFollow) {
        self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading;
        return;
    }

    if (self.mapView.userTrackingMode == MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading) {
        self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeNone;
        return;
    }

    if (self.mapView.userTrackingMode == MKUserTrackingModeNone) {
        self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;
    }
}
```

when mode = `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` annotations begin to put themselves in random order. It seems that in this mode mapview begin to redraw itself  every second and put all the subview (annotations) in unknown order.

How to cancel changing order of annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array of annotations that you get back from `mapview.annotations` is not guaranteed to be in the same order you that added them in. If you are relying on them vein in a special order you are probably doing your `viewForAnnotations` function wrong. It is given an `annotation` as a parameter, you use that to determine what view to draw. Usually people make a custom class that implements the MKAnnotation protocol and has some addition variables in which they store the data needed to create the right view. When `viewForAnnotations` gets called they check if the provided annotation is one of their special class, and if so extract the data, make the view and return it. There is no need to know the order of the annotations array, and it wouldn't do you any good because an MKMapView can and will ask for the annotations in any sequence it likes.

Side note: Why are you writing your own function for toggling the tracking mode? You can just [use the official one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876157/is-the-current-location-compass-heading-button-available-in-the-ios-sdk/9877574#9877574) and it will do it all for you.

Comment: actually this answer didn't help , but anyway I didn't found any other answer. I just put subview to front artfissially.

Comment: If you have put the map view into another subview to rotate the map to match the gps heading just to avoid writing the correct version of `viewForAnnotation`, you're doing it wrong. The annotations are always expected to be in an unknown order. You're supposed to draw the one it is asking for, not the nth one in a particular sequence.